# Why is my caption not centered?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

The caption in my very simple example does ends up left aligned rather than centered. How can I center it?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table} 
    \centering
    \caption{Here is my really long caption that doesn't seem to be centered once it begins a new line}
    \begin{tabular}[htbp!]{ccccc}
    & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: It ends up looking like this]

Comment: that is the expected layout.  a paragraph with individually centred lines is hard to read, latex by default only centres single line captions, multiple line captiosn are a full width parbox

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle has already noted in a comment, what you've encountered is the default behavior under most (nearly all?) document classes.

If you want to override this default and if you want both caption lines to be roughly equal in length, I suggest you (a) load the `ragged2e` and `caption` packages and (b) run `\captionsetup{justification=Centering}` in the preamble. If, on the other hand, you do *not* want the caption's lines to be roughly equally long, I suggest you run `\captionsetup{justification=centering}`.

The lines at the sides of the following screenshot denote the vertical edges of the textblock.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=Centering,
              skip=0.5\baselineskip}
              
\begin{document}

    \begin{table} 
    \centering
    \caption{Here is my really long caption that 
             is now centered across both lines}
             
    \begin{tabular}[htbp]{|ccccc|}
    \hline
    (0) & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much.